# What is the correct `browser compatible` way to change a style attribute?

Tags: javascript, dom

The following code is not working, it is alerting the correct values but will not change `style="display: none;"` to `style="display: block;"`

```
function toggleZoomImage(id, state){
    alert(id);
    alert(state);
    if(state == 'open'){
        document.getElementById(id).style.display == "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display == "none";
    }   
}
```

Comment: Use `=` (assignment) instead of `==` (loose comparison for equality).

Comment: Does anyone know if all current browsers (including mobile) support style.display = "" ?

Comment: The result of setting `style.display = ''` *should* be the same as writing an inline `style="display: ;"` attribute - the browser should ignore this invalid declaration and use whatever value `display` has set in CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function toggleZoomImage(id, state){
    alert(id);
    alert(state);
    if(state == 'open'){
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
    }   
}
```

lose the double equal sign those are comparison operators. Single is assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong operator - use "=" isntead of "==". The first is assignment, which is what you want. The second is a comparison, and isn't doing anything in your code.

Comment: Thank you sir - throwing my equals and assignments around like that is NOT healthy ;) ... wish I could delete the question now.